# Storing redirect response in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, redirect, django-views, django-request

I have a simple python function inside my Django app's views.py:

```
def some_function(requests):
return redirect('some_url')
```

The redirect returns some useful information that I want to use later in the other function. Is there any way I can store the response URL given by the redirect in a variable so that I can use it later in my app. Thanks

Comment: You should not store such things. A webserver should be *stateless*, so you do not store items in memory except for the database and the file system. Doing so would make the system unscalable and error-prone.

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem , It's just for testing purpose and not for any real production app, thanks.

Comment: I would consider that even more horrifying. :)

Comment: It's not that I want to store, it's just a chain of APIs where I am hitting the second API with the response received from the first URL :) Nothing horrifying I guess.